# Run my javascript code on wordpress pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress

In a question asked earlier on stackoverflow I came to a correct javascript code. I then implemented this on my wordpress page (see: [specific page](https://www.spandoekabraham.nl/test/)).

Although the javascript code is loaded in the head (below the js code), it is not activated as soon as I reach the webpage.

```js
let days = ["Zondag","Maandag","Dinsdag","Woensdag","Donderdag","Vrijdag","Zaterdag"];
let months = ["Januari","Februari","Maart","April","Mei","Juni","Juli","Augustus","September","Oktober","November","December"];

let d = new Date();

d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6);
if (d.getDay() === 0)
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
else if (d.getDay() === 6)
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2)

document.getElementById("dag").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()];
document.getElementById("datum").innerHTML = d.getDate();
document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = months[d.getMonth()];

let s = new Date();

s.setDate(s.getDate() + 3 );
if (s.getDay() === 0)
    s.setDate(s.getDate() + 2)
else if (s.getDay() === 6)
    s.setDate(s.getDate() + 3)

document.getElementById("dag-spoed").innerHTML = days[s.getDay()];
document.getElementById("datum-spoed").innerHTML = s.getDate();
document.getElementById("maand-spoed").innerHTML = months[s.getMonth()];
```

```css
.verzending p{     
margin-top: 0px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
padding-right: 5px !important;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="verzending">

<strong>GRATIS verzenden:</strong> Binnen 6 werkdagen verzonden<br>
<p><strong>Verwachte verzenddatum:</strong> <p id="dag"></p><p id="datum"></p><p id="maand"></p></p>

<br>
<br>
<strong>SPOED verzenden:</strong> Binnen 3 werkdagen verzonden:<br>
<p><strong>Verwachte verzenddatum:</strong> <p id="dag-spoed"></p><p id="datum-spoed"></p><p id="maand-spoed"></p></p>
</div>
```

I need help to run the script on my wordpress page(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put it in the header and run, those codes may not be applicable because the Dom is not rendered yet. You may want to try wrapping your codes in the load event.

```
function initialize() {
   //add ur codes here.
}
window.addEventListener('load', initialize)
```

Comment: I updated the codes, where u initialize your codes first, before addEventListener

Comment: Thanks, the first code was working already. In the first instance I didn't place the function line at the right place.